# Viewing android.jar files in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I have a question on viewing android.jar files in Android studio.

I'm looking at the android.jar in Android API 19 platform.

There is a class, AlarmManager.java
The class contains a variable: private final IAlarmManager mService;
IAlarmManager is red, and I'm seeing "Cannot resolve symbol IAlarmManager"

Why isn't the interface being recognized?
How can I view the code for the interface? Is there a setting I need to enable in Android Studio?
Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: `IAlarmManager` is from the platform source code; AFAIK the Android SDK only contains SDK classes.

Comment: Do you know how I can view the platform source code? Or is that hidden? There's only information on AlarmManager on the Android Developer page. Nothing for IAlarmManager.

Comment: "Do you know how I can view the platform source code?" -- I use https://cs.android.com/. "There's only information on AlarmManager on the Android Developer page" -- that is because it is not part of the Android SDK.